# python: sum last and largest cells for each category

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, sum

given this dataframe, I want to extract and sum the last cells in 'y' for every category in 'x'.
For example, the last cell in 'y' for category  A in'x' is 4, for B is 5  and for C is 8,
I therefore want to see 4 + 5+ 8= 17.
How do I do that? and what if I want to sum the largest numbers for each category? So in this case it would be the largest in A (5) + largest in B (9)  +  largest in C (8).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
 data=[['A', 1,2 ,5, 'blue'],
        ['A', 5,5,6, 'blue'],
        ['A', 4,6,7, 'blue']
        ,['B', 6,5,4,'yellow'],
        ['B',9,9,3, 'blue'],
        ['B', 7,9,1,'yellow']
        ,['B', 2,3,1,'yellow'],
        ['B', 5,1,2,'yellow'],
        ['C',2,10,9,'green']
        ,['C', 8,2,8,'green'],
        ['C', 5,4,3,'green'],
        ['C', 8,5 ,3,'green']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x','y','z','xy', 'color'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `groupby` either way:

```
>>> df.groupby("x")["y"].last().sum()
17
>>> df.groupby("x")["y"].max().sum()
22
```

Comment: combine them `df.groupby("x")["y"].agg(['last','max']).sum()`

Comment: Yup but I think the way the question was structured, it sounded like two different questions!